Issues with circleci related to gitversion
I have a circleci pipeline that generates a nuget package, and uploads it to nuget.org.
So far It has been working just fine however It suddenly stopped working.
This is the error

Here's the config.yml
version: 2.1

jobs:

  build-and-test:
    docker:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
    steps:

      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Cambiar directorio
          command: cd ./Repo
         
      - run:
          name: Instalar Node
          command: apk add nodejs

      - run:
          name: Instalar NPM
          command: apk add npm

      - run:
          working_directory: ./Repo
          name: Ejecutar tests
          command: |
            dotnet test
            << pipeline.git.tag >>
      - run:
          working_directory: ./Repo
          name: Compilar version Release
          command: |
            dotnet build --configuration Release

      - run:
          name: Patchear imagen
          command: |
            apk add openssh git jq

      - run:
          name: Generar manifest
          command: |
            dotnet new tool-manifest

      - run:
          name: Instalar GitVersion
          command: |
            dotnet tool install GitVersion.Tool

      - run:
          working_directory: ./Repo/Components
          name: Generar paquete nuget
          command: |
            VERSION=$(dotnet gitversion | jq -r ".SemVer") 
            dotnet pack --configuration Release -p:Version=$VERSION -o ./outputs/packages/
            
      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./Repo/Components/outputs/packages
          destination: packages

      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ./Repo/Components/outputs/packages
          paths:
            - "*.nupkg"
            - "*.snupkg"
  push:
    docker:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: /tmp/workspace
      - run:
          name: Pushear a Nuget.org
          command: dotnet nuget push /tmp/workspace/*.* --api-key someapikey --skip-duplicate --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

workflows:
  setup:
    when:
      and:
        - equal: [ main, << pipeline.git.branch >> ]
    jobs:
      - build-and-test:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - push:
          requires:
            - build-and-test
          context:
            - NuGet
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)$/

I've been investigating and recently I upgraded the system to .NET Core 8.0. Apparently Gitversion is now version 6.0 in order to be compatible with Net 8.0. https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/main/BREAKING_CHANGES.md
I also tried replacing the jq library with fx, but I get this error SyntaxError: JSON value expected on line 1. I think dotnet gitversion is not outputting a proper json object.

I finally solved it by taking a look at the GitVersion.yml.
I was using gitversion 6 in my pipeline, and gitversion 5 in my local environment so that's why I wasn't able to reproduce the error.
Gitversion 6 contains breaking changes.
First I make sure that the config.yml from circleci was valid (I used the circleci-cli for that task.)
Then I updated gitversion to V6.0 in my local environment.
Then I was able to reproduce the same error as the one reported by circle ci.
It ended up being a malformed file (Gitversion.yml), some properties were renamed. By making sure the configuration file is valid it started working again. I haven't made any more changes besides fixing the config file.
Hope someone finds this useful.
